# C++: Providing a stream insertion operator for a typedef'ed vector of unsigned ints within a namespace

Tags: c++, vector, stl, namespaces, c++17

First of all: I'm not an expert in C++ but I'm writing C++ bindings for a low-level C library and need some help to take the correct approach.

Below is the problem I'm facing abstracted into a simple example (see comments):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>

// We have a namespace N.
namespace N {

// And a nested namespace NN.
namespace NN {

// A scoped enum E.
enum class E {
    FIRST = 1,
    SECOND,
};

// And a typedef for a vector holding E values.
using EV = ::std::vector<E>;

// We want to make E printable so let's provide a mapping of values
// to human-readable names ...
const ::std::map<E, ::std::string> E_names = {
    { E::FIRST, "FIRST" },
    { E::SECOND, "SECOND" }
};

// ... and stream insertion operator for the enum ...
::std::ostream& operator<<(::std::ostream& out, E e)
{
    out << E_names.at(e);

    return out;
}

// ... and for the vector.
::std::ostream& operator<<(::std::ostream& out, const EV& ev)
{
    out << "(";
    ::std::copy(ev.begin(), ::std::prev(ev.end()),
            ::std::ostream_iterator<E>(out, ", "));
    out << ev.back();
    out << ")";

    return out;
}

} /* namespace NN */

// Now back in namespace N, let's define the following class:
class A
{
public:
    explicit A(void) {}

    void m(const NN::EV& ev) {}

    NN::EV get_ev(void) const { return NN::EV({ NN::E::FIRST, NN::E::SECOND}); }
};

// And its own stream insertion operator:
::std::ostream& operator<<(::std::ostream& out, const A& a)
{
    out << "A(" << a.get_ev() << ")";

    return out;
}

} /* namespace N */

// And do the following in main():
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ::std::cout << N::NN::E::FIRST << ::std::endl;

    ::std::cout << N::NN::EV({ N::NN::E::FIRST, N::NN::E::SECOND }) << ::std::endl;

    ::std::cout << N::A().get_ev() << ::std::endl;

    ::std::cout << N::A() << ::std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The above works fine. Now let's extend the example as follows:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>

namespace N {

namespace NN {

enum class E {
    FIRST = 1,
    SECOND,
};

using EV = ::std::vector<E>;
// Let's add another typedef for a vector holding unsigned integers.
using UV = ::std::vector<unsigned int>;

const ::std::map<E, ::std::string> E_names = {
    { E::FIRST, "FIRST" },
    { E::SECOND, "SECOND" }
};

::std::ostream& operator<<(::std::ostream& out, E e)
{
    out << E_names.at(e);

    return out;
}

::std::ostream& operator<<(::std::ostream& out, const EV& ev)
{
    out << "(";
    ::std::copy(ev.begin(), ::std::prev(ev.end()),
            ::std::ostream_iterator<E>(out, ", "));
    out << ev.back();
    out << ")";

    return out;
}

// And define the following stream insertion operator.
::std::ostream& operator<<(::std::ostream& out, const UV& uv)
{
    out << "(";
    ::std::copy(uv.begin(), ::std::prev(uv.end()),
            ::std::ostream_iterator<unsigned int>(out, ", "));
    out << uv.back();
    out << ")";

    return out;
}

} /* namespace NN */

class A
{
public:
    explicit A(void) {}

    void m(const NN::EV& ev) {}

    NN::EV get_ev(void) const { return NN::EV({ NN::E::FIRST, NN::E::SECOND}); }

    NN::UV get_uv(void) const { return NN::UV({ 10, 20 }); }
};

::std::ostream& operator<<(::std::ostream& out, const A& a)
{
    out << "A(" << a.get_ev() << ", " << a.get_uv() << ")";

    return out;
}

} /* namespace N */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ::std::cout << N::NN::E::FIRST << ::std::endl;

    ::std::cout << N::NN::EV({ N::NN::E::FIRST, N::NN::E::SECOND }) << ::std::endl;

    ::std::cout << N::A().get_ev() << ::std::endl;

    ::std::cout << N::A().get_uv() << ::std::endl;

    ::std::cout << N::A() << ::std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Now the following splat is generated by gcc:

```
ostest.cpp: In function ‘std::ostream& N::operator<<(std::ostream&, const N::A&)’:
ostest.cpp:68:36: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ and ‘N::NN::UV’ {aka ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’})
   68 |  out << "A(" << a.get_ev() << ", " << a.get_uv() << ")";
      |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~ ~~~~~~~~~~
      |                            |                  |
      |                            |                  N::NN::UV {aka std::vector<unsigned int>}
      |                            std::basic_ostream<char>
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/iostream:39,
                 from ostest.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:108:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  108 |       operator<<(__ostream_type& (*__pf)(__ostream_type&))
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:108:36: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘N::NN::UV’ {aka ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’} to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type&)’ {aka ‘std::basic_ostream<char>& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>&)’}
  108 |       operator<<(__ostream_type& (*__pf)(__ostream_type&))
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:117:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ios_type = std::basic_ios<char>]’
  117 |       operator<<(__ios_type& (*__pf)(__ios_type&))
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:117:32: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘N::NN::UV’ {aka ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’} to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>::__ios_type& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>::__ios_type&)’ {aka ‘std::basic_ios<char>& (*)(std::basic_ios<char>&)’}
  117 |       operator<<(__ios_type& (*__pf)(__ios_type&))
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:127:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  127 |       operator<<(ios_base& (*__pf) (ios_base&))
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:127:30: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘N::NN::UV’ {aka ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’} to ‘std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)’
  127 |       operator<<(ios_base& (*__pf) (ios_base&))
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:166:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  166 |       operator<<(long __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:166:23: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘N::NN::UV’ {aka ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’} to ‘long int’
  166 |       operator<<(long __n)
      |                  ~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:170:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  170 |       operator<<(unsigned long __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:170:32: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘N::NN::UV’ {aka ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’} to ‘long unsigned int’
  170 |       operator<<(unsigned long __n)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:174:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(bool) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  174 |       operator<<(bool __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:174:23: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘N::NN::UV’ {aka ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’} to ‘bool’
  174 |       operator<<(bool __n)
      |                  ~~~~~^~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/ostream:784,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/iostream:39,
                 from ostest.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/ostream.tcc:91:5: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’
   91 |     basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/ostream.tcc:92:22: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘N::NN::UV’ {aka ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’} to ‘short int’
   92 |     operator<<(short __n)
      |                ~~~~~~^~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/iostream:39,
                 from ostest.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:181:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short unsigned int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  181 |       operator<<(unsigned short __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:181:33: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘N::NN::UV’ {aka ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’} to ‘short unsigned int’
  181 |       operator<<(unsigned short __n)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/ostream:784,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/iostream:39,
                 from ostest.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/ostream.tcc:105:5: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’
  105 |     basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/ostream.tcc:106:20: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘N::NN::UV’ {aka ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’} to ‘int’
  106 |     operator<<(int __n)
      |                ~~~~^~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/iostream:39,
                 from ostest.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:192:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(unsigned int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  192 |       operator<<(unsigned int __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:192:31: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘N::NN::UV’ {aka ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’} to ‘unsigned int’
  192 |       operator<<(unsigned int __n)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:201:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  201 |       operator<<(long long __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:201:28: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘N::NN::UV’ {aka ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’} to ‘long long int’
  201 |       operator<<(long long __n)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:205:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  205 |       operator<<(unsigned long long __n)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:205:37: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘N::NN::UV’ {aka ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’} to ‘long long unsigned int’
  205 |       operator<<(unsigned long long __n)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:220:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(double) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  220 |       operator<<(double __f)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:220:25: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘N::NN::UV’ {aka ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’} to ‘double’
  220 |       operator<<(double __f)
      |                  ~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:224:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(float) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  224 |       operator<<(float __f)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:224:24: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘N::NN::UV’ {aka ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’} to ‘float’
  224 |       operator<<(float __f)
      |                  ~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:232:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long double) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  232 |       operator<<(long double __f)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:232:30: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘N::NN::UV’ {aka ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’} to ‘long double’
  232 |       operator<<(long double __f)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:245:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(const void*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
  245 |       operator<<(const void* __p)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:245:30: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘N::NN::UV’ {aka ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’} to ‘const void*’
  245 |       operator<<(const void* __p)
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:250:7: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::nullptr_t) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>; std::nullptr_t = std::nullptr_t]’
  250 |       operator<<(nullptr_t)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:250:18: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘N::NN::UV’ {aka ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’} to ‘std::nullptr_t’
  250 |       operator<<(nullptr_t)
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/ostream:784,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/iostream:39,
                 from ostest.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/ostream.tcc:119:5: note: candidate: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type = std::basic_streambuf<char>]’
  119 |     basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/ostream.tcc:120:34: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘N::NN::UV’ {aka ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’} to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>::__streambuf_type*’ {aka ‘std::basic_streambuf<char>*’}
  120 |     operator<<(__streambuf_type* __sbin)
      |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
ostest.cpp:66:17: note: candidate: ‘std::ostream& N::operator<<(std::ostream&, const N::A&)’
   66 | ::std::ostream& operator<<(::std::ostream& out, const A& a)
      |                 ^~~~~~~~
ostest.cpp:66:58: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘N::NN::UV’ {aka ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’} to ‘const N::A&’
   66 | ::std::ostream& operator<<(::std::ostream& out, const A& a)
      |                                                 ~~~~~~~~~^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/bits/basic_string.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/string:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/iostream:39,
                 from ostest.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/10/string_view:619:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>)’
  619 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/string_view:619:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
ostest.cpp:68:48: note:   ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’ is not derived from ‘std::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>’
   68 |  out << "A(" << a.get_ev() << ", " << a.get_uv() << ")";
      |                                                ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/string:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/iostream:39,
                 from ostest.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/basic_string.h:6468:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>&)’
 6468 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/basic_string.h:6468:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
ostest.cpp:68:48: note:   ‘N::NN::UV’ {aka ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’} is not derived from ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>’
   68 |  out << "A(" << a.get_ev() << ", " << a.get_uv() << ")";
      |                                                ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/bits/ios_base.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/iostream:39,
                 from ostest.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/10/system_error:262:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::error_code&)’
  262 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os, const error_code& __e)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/system_error:262:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
ostest.cpp:68:47: note:   cannot convert ‘N::A::get_uv() const()’ (type ‘N::NN::UV’ {aka ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’}) to type ‘const std::error_code&’
   68 |  out << "A(" << a.get_ev() << ", " << a.get_uv() << ")";
      |                                       ~~~~~~~~^~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/iostream:39,
                 from ostest.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:506:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT)’
  506 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __out, _CharT __c)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:506:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
ostest.cpp:68:48: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘_CharT’ (‘char’ and ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’)
   68 |  out << "A(" << a.get_ev() << ", " << a.get_uv() << ")";
      |                                                ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/iostream:39,
                 from ostest.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:511:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, char)’
  511 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __out, char __c)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:511:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
ostest.cpp:68:47: note:   cannot convert ‘N::A::get_uv() const()’ (type ‘N::NN::UV’ {aka ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’}) to type ‘char’
   68 |  out << "A(" << a.get_ev() << ", " << a.get_uv() << ")";
      |                                       ~~~~~~~~^~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/iostream:39,
                 from ostest.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:517:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, char)’
  517 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, char __c)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:517:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
ostest.cpp:68:47: note:   cannot convert ‘N::A::get_uv() const()’ (type ‘N::NN::UV’ {aka ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’}) to type ‘char’
   68 |  out << "A(" << a.get_ev() << ", " << a.get_uv() << ")";
      |                                       ~~~~~~~~^~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/iostream:39,
                 from ostest.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:523:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, signed char)’
  523 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, signed char __c)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:523:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
ostest.cpp:68:47: note:   cannot convert ‘N::A::get_uv() const()’ (type ‘N::NN::UV’ {aka ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’}) to type ‘signed char’
   68 |  out << "A(" << a.get_ev() << ", " << a.get_uv() << ")";
      |                                       ~~~~~~~~^~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/iostream:39,
                 from ostest.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:528:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char)’
  528 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, unsigned char __c)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:528:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
ostest.cpp:68:47: note:   cannot convert ‘N::A::get_uv() const()’ (type ‘N::NN::UV’ {aka ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’}) to type ‘unsigned char’
   68 |  out << "A(" << a.get_ev() << ", " << a.get_uv() << ")";
      |                                       ~~~~~~~~^~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/iostream:39,
                 from ostest.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:589:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const _CharT*)’
  589 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __out, const _CharT* __s)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:589:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
ostest.cpp:68:48: note:   mismatched types ‘const _CharT*’ and ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’
   68 |  out << "A(" << a.get_ev() << ", " << a.get_uv() << ")";
      |                                                ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/ostream:784,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/iostream:39,
                 from ostest.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/ostream.tcc:321:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _CharT, class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const char*)’
  321 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __out, const char* __s)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/ostream.tcc:321:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
ostest.cpp:68:47: note:   cannot convert ‘N::A::get_uv() const()’ (type ‘N::NN::UV’ {aka ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’}) to type ‘const char*’
   68 |  out << "A(" << a.get_ev() << ", " << a.get_uv() << ")";
      |                                       ~~~~~~~~^~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/iostream:39,
                 from ostest.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:606:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, const char*)’
  606 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, const char* __s)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:606:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
ostest.cpp:68:47: note:   cannot convert ‘N::A::get_uv() const()’ (type ‘N::NN::UV’ {aka ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’}) to type ‘const char*’
   68 |  out << "A(" << a.get_ev() << ", " << a.get_uv() << ")";
      |                                       ~~~~~~~~^~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/iostream:39,
                 from ostest.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:619:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, const signed char*)’
  619 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, const signed char* __s)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:619:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
ostest.cpp:68:47: note:   cannot convert ‘N::A::get_uv() const()’ (type ‘N::NN::UV’ {aka ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’}) to type ‘const signed char*’
   68 |  out << "A(" << a.get_ev() << ", " << a.get_uv() << ")";
      |                                       ~~~~~~~~^~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/iostream:39,
                 from ostest.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:624:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, const unsigned char*)’
  624 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, const unsigned char* __s)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:624:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
ostest.cpp:68:47: note:   cannot convert ‘N::A::get_uv() const()’ (type ‘N::NN::UV’ {aka ‘std::vector<unsigned int>’}) to type ‘const unsigned char*’
   68 |  out << "A(" << a.get_ev() << ", " << a.get_uv() << ")";
      |                                       ~~~~~~~~^~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/iostream:39,
                 from ostest.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/10/ostream:773:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Ostream, class _Tp> typename std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::__not_<std::is_lvalue_reference<_Tp> >, std::__is_convertible_to_basic_ostream<_Ostream>, std::__is_insertable<typename std::__is_convertible_to_basic_ostream<_Tp>::__ostream_type, const _Tp&, void> >::value, typename std::__is_convertible_to_basic_ostream<_Tp>::__ostream_type>::type std::operator<<(_Ostream&&, const _Tp&)’
  773 |     operator<<(_Ostream&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
      |     ^~~~~~~~

[snip]
```

Ok so I can't specialize vector like that. Let's do this:

```cpp
struct printable_UV
{
    printable_UV(const UV& uv) : ref(uv) {}
    const UV& ref;
};

::std::ostream& operator<<(::std::ostream& out, const printable_UV& uv)
{
    out << "(";
    ::std::copy(uv.ref.begin(), ::std::prev(uv.ref.end()),
            ::std::ostream_iterator<unsigned int>(out, ", "));
    out << uv.ref.back();
    out << ")";

    return out;
}
```

The splat is still there. But if I go with a simpler example with no namespaces like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using vec = ::std::vector<unsigned int>;

struct printable
{
    const vec& ref;
    printable(const vec& v) : ref(v) {}
};

::std::ostream& operator<<(::std::ostream& out, const printable& v)
{
    out << "(";
    ::std::copy(v.ref.begin(), ::std::prev(v.ref.end()),
            ::std::ostream_iterator<unsigned int>(out, ", "));
    out << v.ref.back();
    out << ")";

    return out;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    vec v = { 1, 2, 3 };

    ::std::cout << v << ::std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It works just fine. This makes me think that introducing namespaces makes the lookup fail. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `::` -- There is no need to specify the global scope resolution operator in most places in your code, maybe all places in your code.  You also forgot `#include <string>`.

Comment: The namespace lookup for `UV` will be done in `std` (for both `std::ostream` and `std::vector<int>`). Ugly fix: `struct EV : std::vector<E> { using std::vector<E>::vector; };` and `struct UV : std::vector<unsigned int> { using std::vector<unsigned int>::vector; };` - Now the lookup will succeed

Comment: `std::copy` -- You also forgot `<algorithm>`.  Even though your code compiled with the version of the compiler you're using, there is no guarantee that the code will compile on future versions of the compiler (or other compilers) with the missing header(s).

Comment: *but I'm writing C++ bindings for a low-level C library* -- To be honest, I've never seen a C++ binding for a C library attempt to resort to what you're trying to accomplish.  I would expect the `C` "stuff" to be put in classes, and have some sort of way to build up the C++ class from the low-level C constructs.

Comment: @TedLyngmo - `EV` Can be an alias just fine. The associated namespaces of template argument contribute to ADL.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Yepp, my bad. The failed lookup only affects `UV`.